# ¿Debo crear un modelo de una tabla pivote?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

Quiero unir la tabla `destinations_travels`(tabla pivote entre `travels` y `destinations`) con users en otra tabla pivote que sería `destinations_travels_users`, mi duda viene a la hora de hacer la relación entre moedelos, ya que cuando hago el belongs to many en usuarios tengo que referirme a un modelo(`destinations_travel`) tabla la cual no tiene modelo, ¿creo modelo de la tabla aunque sea tabla pivote? ¿que nombre debería ponerle en ese caso? gracias de antemano

//tabla destinations_travels (es una tabla pivote)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('destinations_travels_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('rating');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->string('start_date');
        $table->string('ending_date');


        $table->integer('destinations_travel_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('users_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

        $table->foreign('destinations_travel_id')->references('id')->on('destinations_travels');
        $table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

//tabla User

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('profile');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('email');


        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

//tabla destinations_travels_users

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('destinations_travels_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('rating');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->string('start_date');
        $table->string('ending_date');


        $table->integer('destinations_travel_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('users_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

        $table->foreign('destinations_travel_id')->references('id')->on('destinations_travels');
        $table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

//Este codigo es en el que me refiero que debería dejar el modelo de users

```
public function destinations_travels(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(::class)
        ->withPivot('rating','image','start_date','ending_date')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Comment: Puedes crear un modelo para la tabla pívot, pero no es necesario. Basta con definir la relación entre DestinationsTravel y User.

Comment: Para las tablas pivot no es necesario su representación a través de una entidad, podrás realizar acciones sobre los datos en ella a través de las relaciones que declares en los otros 2 modelos y los métodos: sync, attach, etc que ya provee Eloquent

Comment: igual no me he explicado bien @porloscerrosΨ  una de las dos tablas que uno a través de la tabla pivote destinations_travels_users ya es pivote(la tabla destinations_travels) por tanto a la hora de hacer en el modelo user el public function destinations_travels(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(::class)
            ->withPivot('rating','image','start_date','ending_date')->withTimestamps();
    } en el parentesis antes de los 4 puntos de class debe ir el modelo de la tabla destination_travels no?

Comment: igual no me he explicado bien @BetaM de las dos tablas que uno a través de la tabla pivote destinations_travels_users ya es pivote(la tabla destinations_travels) por tanto a la hora de hacer en el modelo user el public function destinations_travels(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(::class)
            ->withPivot('rating','image','start_date','ending_date')->withTimestamps();
    } en el parentesis antes de los 4 puntos de class debe ir el modelo de la tabla destination_travels no?

Comment: Es muy difícil leer ese código en el comentario, por favor agrégalo a la pregunta

Comment: El primer argumento es el modelo con el cual esta relacionado el actual, el segundo argumento  es el nombre de la tabla pivote, el tercer argumento es la llave foránea que identfica al modelo actual y el último argumento es la llave foránea del modelo al que apuntas con la relación: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: cierto, ya está agregado @porloscerrosΨ

Answer (score 0):

Como ejemplo asumamos que tienes 3 tablas:

- travels
- destinations
- destinations_travels_users

Posterior al ser una [relación muchos a muchos](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) deberás usar las relaciones que provee Eloquent de esta forma:

Modelo Travel

```
class Travel extends Model 
{
    public function destinations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Destination::class, 
                                    'destinations_travels_users',
                                    'llave_foranea_modelo_travel',
                                    'llave_foranea_modelo_destionations'
                                    );
    }
}
```

Modelo Destination

```
class Destination extends Model 
{
    public function travels()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Travel::class,
                                    'destinations_travels_users'
                                    'llave_foranea_modelo_destination',
                                    'llave_foranea_modelo_travel'
                                    );
    }
}
```

No hace falta como te comentaba un modelo para la tabla pivote, pues a ella la operarás mediante las relaciones que declares y los métodos que el propio eloquent ya [dispone para ello](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Lo que tu tabla pivote: **`destinations_travels_users`** debe tener es la declaración de las llaves foráneas que ayudarán a vincularla con las otras tablas

- Considera que si sigues las convenciones de nombre de Eloquent entonces desde el argumento 2 al 4 no se ocupan
- Como tu tabla pivote no sigue dicha convención entonces es necesario colocarla
- Tus llaves foráneas tampoco siguen la convención entonces también se hace necesario que las declares

Comment: Entiendo lo que me dices, pero el problema está en que relaciono una tabla pivote con otra normal, en usuarios tengo que relacionarla con destination_travel(que ya es una tabla pivote de por si), no se si lo entiendes